# Mysql query syntax for conditional inserts

Tags: mysql, sql

> In following example I want to insert in table only if there is no
>   data otherwise it is giving PK violation. How to do conditional insert in mysql. Please note I am using mysql db.

```
create table if not exists visa_amt_conversion (
  last_char char(1) not null,
  last_digit char(1) not null,
  tran_sign char(1) not null,
  primary key (last_char)
 );

insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('{', '0', '+');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('A', '1', '+');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('B', '2', '+');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('C', '3', '+');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('D', '4', '+'); 
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('E', '5', '+');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('F', '6', '+'); 
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('G', '7', '+');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('H', '8', '+'); 
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('I', '9', '+');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('}', '0', '-'); 
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('J', '1', '-');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('K', '2', '-'); 
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('L', '3', '-');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('M', '4', '-');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('N', '5', '-');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('O', '6', '-');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('P', '7', '-');
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('Q', '8', '-'); 
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign) VALUES ('R', '9', '-');
```

Comment: `insert into ingnore....`

Comment: Thanks added insert ignore into ....  Please add it as answer so I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do this is something like:

```
insert into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign)
    VALUES ('{', '0', '+')
    on duplicate key update last_char = values(last_char);
```

If an attempt is made to insert values that violate a unique or primary key constraint, then the row is updated instead.  The `last_char = values(last_char))` is a no-op.  Because the value doesn't change, the row isn't even updated.

The shorter syntax:

```
insert ignore into visa_amt_conversion (last_char, last_digit, tran_sign)
    VALUES ('{', '0', '+');
```

does the same thing *in this case*.  However, it is not recommended because it ignores all errors.  It is better to use the first version, because it ignores only the specific error that you want to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

What about

`select count(last_char) from visa_amt_conversion;`

If that query returns 0, table is empty. If you get an error, table doesn't exists.

Comment: How does count check if a table exists or not.. if you query a non existing table you get a error

Comment: @RaymondNijland true, i've just edit that. Last time i tried that was in pg database and it worked.